# No IDEA annotations attached to the JDK

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jdk11

> No IDEA annotations attached to the JDK 1.8 (D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211), some issues will not be found

С чем связанно возникновение этой надписи, и что с этим делать?

[image]

Comment: Запостите текст текстом, пожалуйста. И дайте вопросу более толковое название )

Comment: Там же у вас справа есть кнопка-ссылка: «Attach annotations».

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Он добавляет jdkAnnotations.jar в конфигурацию JDK:[image: Idea]

Этот файл-JAR нужен для предоставления внешних аннотаций для методов JDK: 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/external-annotations.html и
Magic Constant преверяет наличие таких аннотаций:
https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/02/new-magic-constant-inspection/

Либо попробуй так : "File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart..."